# Keyboard Shortcut to add a new Artboard in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shortcuts

Is there a single shortcut to create a new artboard in Illustrator?
If not how could I set one up?

Comment: Judging by your recent questions, you might benefit from this article: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Comment: Hey Vince thanks for replying to my post. Ah yes I've read through that doc only to find that the simple act of adding a new art board with a key word shortcut was not in that doc, hence my post. Yup I def don't just post here before trying to find answers online first, hope that addresses your concerns an possible down vote. Just looking for an answer to what should be a simple Q, but sometimes in Adobe land what should be simple isn't always so.

Comment: Sadly, the answer seems to (still) be no.

Comment: Vincent didn't do his own homework... why link to an article when the answer is not there?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up keyboard shortcuts in Illustrator through <kbd>Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts</kbd>. At least on Win, it's possibly in <kbd>Illustrator</kbd> on Mac; the shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl/ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

If a certain action is not in that list, it's very well possible you can't create a shortcut for it at all. I suspect that to create a new artboard, you'd have to enter location and size, and Illustrator can't make anything without you entering those. In that case, you might want to make an action out of it and assign a shortcut to that action.

Comment: _"...Illustrator can't make anything without you entering those."_ That's exactly what the stock **New Artboard** button (in the **Artboards** menu) does. It will copy the dimensions of the most recently created artboard and place it to the immediate righthand side of said artboard with a small margin. The problem is it can't be assigned a keyboard shortcut, because.. Adobe. I can't seem to be able to record it as an action either.